# Finding a single record by id with ember and ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Why can't I pass the Id as a parameter in this scenario:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("home", {path: '/'});
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
           // return this.store.find('post');//works
            return this.store.find('post',1);//does not
        },
        setupController: function (controller, model) {
            controller.set('info', model);
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bfsddvo/2/

Ref:
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_finding-a-single-record

I know I am trying to do this from my 'home' route so I would guess that if a created a `posts/[:id]` route it would all work a lot better.

How can I return only one post in my home route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved your jsfiddle to a jsbin and worked through the errors (it's a lot easier to debug jsbins).  I was able to see this error in the console which gave a good starting point:

```
Error while processing route: home Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('info', <App.Post:ember353:1>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.HomeController:ember393>: its 'content' is undefined. Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('info', <App.Post:ember353:1>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.HomeController:ember393>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

I'm honestly not 100% sure why this works, but I got your example working by making these changes.

First I added an explicit controller for `HomeController`:

```
App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});
```

Then, in your template, you don't have anything to iterate over so you can just display the model directly:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{info.id}} - {{info.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/diqakixapo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ok cool, yes that makes sense. I couldn't find any indication of having to use a controller in most tutorials and docs I found. Thanks